# how open a link in java swing with help of mini browser newly created

Tags: java, swingx

searching result show as hyperlink

[image]

it can't open on my mini browser newly created

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void openWebpage(URI uri) { 
    Desktop desktop = Desktop.isDesktopSupported() ? Desktop.getDesktop() : null;
    if (desktop != null && desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.BROWSE)) { 
        try { 
            desktop.browse(uri); 
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); } 
    } 
} 

public static void openWebpage(URL url) { 
    try { 
        openWebpage(url.toURI()); 
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: by using this code link open in default browser in system(like Mozilla, internet explore..) I want to open in mini browser newly create. What change were made in this code